# VBA Excel Loop Copy and Paste

Tags: vba, loops, copy, offset, paste

I am trying to loop a code so I do not have to manually type in the cell range every time.

Sub copy()

```
Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range
Set x = Range("C24361:F24363")
Set y = Range("P1")

x.copy
y.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(5, 0).copy
y.Offset(3, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(10, 0).copy
y.Offset(6, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(15, 0).copy
y.Offset(9, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(54, 0).copy
y.Offset(12, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(59, 0).copy
y.Offset(15, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(64, 0).copy
y.Offset(18, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(69, 0).copy
y.Offset(21, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(108, 0).copy
y.Offset(24, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(113, 0).copy
y.Offset(27, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(118, 0).copy
y.Offset(30, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(123, 0).copy
y.Offset(33, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(162, 0).copy
y.Offset(36, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(167, 0).copy
y.Offset(39, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(172, 0).copy
y.Offset(42, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

x.Offset(177, 0).copy
y.Offset(45, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Sub

Right now I grab the range specified...and drop three copy..paste..etc..once 4 copies are made...I need to drop 54 and run the same drop 5 copy (so 59)..and continue the 3 drop for the paste...Any clues on how I can accomplish this task?

THANK YOU

Comment: slightly confused... so first it is `5,10,15,54` and then it is `5,10,15,59` or `10,15,20,59`?

Comment: Yeah. So It is a copy then move down 5,10,15, then 54 (these are separated by 5), so 59,64,69, then 108, 113, 118, 123, then 162 (+5+5 etc)..In English, there are 100s of 4 3x4 copies I need to make and the first cell of each set of 4 3x4s is separated by 54 cells for each city (hence the 54, 108, 162 to start). Make sense? Thank you

Comment: The 54 is to jump to the next set of 4 3x4s since the first cell is 54 away from the original copy I make (in this example C7). Also the reason it jumps five is the first cell for each 3x4 is 5 cells away.

Comment: So what comes after `5,10,15,54`? Can you write a second set of copy paste code in yuor question above so that I can see what do you mean?

Comment: I wrote a few more sets..so after copying the first 4 sets of 3x3 it jumps 54...then you see 3 more sets of 3x3..then 108...3 more sets...162 etc

Comment: Paul has already posted an answer... have a look. If that is not what you are looking for then I will post my answer

Answer (score 0):

For sets:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copySets()
    Const ITERATIONS As Long = 5    'repeated sets of 4 ranges appended
    Const TOTAL_UNIT As Long = 4    'one unit contains 4 ranges
    Const RNG_OFFSET As Long = 2    'one range is 3 rows
    Const TB         As Long = 54   'offset between units

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngRows As Long, setRows As Long, fSet As Range
    Dim cl1R As Long, cl1C As Long, cl2R As Long, cl2C As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With ws
        cl1R = 7:   cl1C = 3:   cl2R = 9:   cl2C = 6  'Range("C7") and Range("F9")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(cl1R, cl1C), .Cells(cl2R, cl2C))

        rngRows = cl2R - cl1R + 1       'rows in range unit
        setRows = rngRows + RNG_OFFSET  'rows in range unit + offset rows between units

        For i = 1 To ITERATIONS
            If fSet Is Nothing Then Set fSet = rng Else Set fSet = Union(fSet, rng)
            For j = 1 To TOTAL_UNIT - 1
                Set fSet = Union(fSet, rng.Offset(setRows * j, 0))
            Next
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(cl1R + (TB * i), cl1C), .Cells(cl2R + (TB * i), cl2C))
        Next

        fSet.Copy .Cells(((rngRows * j) * i) - ((rngRows * TOTAL_UNIT) * i) + 1, 16)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Test file:

### [image: copySets]

**Addition**:

To copy cities:

```
Sub copyCities()
   Const CP As Long = 5    'copy-paste repeated (iterations)
   Const CC As Long = 2    'copy column (Col "B": cities)
   Const CO As Long = 54   'offset between copied cells (cities)
   Const PC As Long = 16   'paste column (Col "P" = 16)
   Const PO As Long = 12   'paste offset

   Dim i As Long

   With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    For i = 0 To CP - 1
     .Range(.Cells((i * PO) + 1, PC), .Cells((i * PO) + PO, PC)) = .Cells((CO * i) + 1, CC)
    Next
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for the code. I have attempted to run it and it does not seem to execute. The data is set up that the first cell for every data range is 54 cells apart. That is why you see 54, 59, 64, 59 for the second copy and paste. The reason there is +5 for each is that for each of the 4 3x4 ranges of data there is a gap of two lines in between. So the first cell of the first range is 5 cells away from the second range (and so on for 2 more times). That is where the 54...108...162 comes from as well as the +5 after each of those.

Comment: In this particular case "a picture is worth 1,000 words" :) I'll make a quick test file and I'll post an image in my answer: let me know how I should adjust it so the code can copy the proper ranges

Comment: OK perfect! Yes it works you are correct. For some reason it stops. What could cause the loop to stop? (Sorry i am an economist not a computer scientist..Is there some way I can specify a point such as C1000000 and make it stop there?

Comment: If you're not referring to any errors, the only reason for it to stop is **`Const ITERATIONS As Long = 5`** (top of the function). Change it from `5` to whatever number of sets you want to copy (a set contains 4 ranges). And no problem if you're not sure about something - just let me know where you're not clear, in whatever terminology ;)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Paul. If I want to do something very similar. Let's say just copy one cell and then run the exact same thing (skip 54, I am grabbing city names now), but I need to paste them 11 spaces away. So for example P1 would be a city name, then P13 would be the next city name. How would I alter this code? I think I have down the copy part (just change the range numbers) but the paste I haven't been able to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Colin, I'm not sure what you mean by 11 spaces (rows?). The copy part is performed by the last line (`fSet.Copy .Cells...`). That line translates to something like: "copy range fSet to .Cells(Row=1, Col=16)". If you want to insert new data in the ranges being copied I'd need to change the ranges and increase their offset accordingly. I'll need a sample of your data file (I don't know where the city names are currently)

Comment: Actually from your explanation above I think I understand how to change the code. But for example: "New York City" is in B1, "Oakland" is in B55, and "Philadelphia" is in B109. I need to copy those by looping through the 54 spaces just like before, but instead of a range it is just one cell. Then for the paste (I misspoke before a little), I would like in P1, it to paste B1, then in P13 paste B55...etc. (that's the skipping 12 spaces, which should have been said by using the word rows). If this doesn't make sense, I can send you a copy of some data.

Comment: A copy of the date would make it a lot faster, but to clarify: you want to be able to 2 distinct copy operations (either cities, or the initial ranges), correct?

Comment: I think just one? Not sure. So copy B1. Paste it in P1. Copy B55. Paste P13. Copy B109. Paste it in P25.. The cities are sepearted in the b column by 54...I need the pastes to be separated by 12 in the p column. Honestly if you could paste B1 in P1:P12, that would be even more amazing. (And B55 in P13:P24 etc. ) I really appreciate all your help man. Does that make sense? It's very similar to the last code.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to figure it out after I have a copy of your file

Comment: Yeah no prob. How do I get you the file?

Comment: sent the file to that email address

Comment: Your last comment provided all details I needed (once I had your file!). I updated the answer to include the 2nd solution and I'll send you the updated file as well